# Angular 13- scss not applied after HTML is returned from a service and appended to document

Tags: html, css, angular, service, angular14

Angular 13-
I have an external html file that I load in an Angular component. After the file is retrieved and the service returns a response, I append the content to the HTML.
The problem is that the styles are not applied in the scss file.
I want a way to reload this scss file when the response is returned from the service.

I tried adding

```
setTheme(theme) {
    window.localStorage.setItem('theme', JSON.stringify(theme));
    this.theme = theme;
    let link = document.getElementById("css-theme");
    if(link) {
        link['href'] = this.theme.url;
    } else {
        let node = document.createElement('link');
        node.href = this.theme.url; // insert url in between quotes
        node.rel = 'stylesheet';
        node.id = 'css-theme';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
    }
}
```

But, I want to refresh the scss file in the angular component, not to append an external link in the head

Comment: Please specify what styles should be applied: global or local component's styles? If later than what is your `encapsulation` for this component? BTW, as was already mentioned in the answer below, do you mean unprocessed SCSS file or compiled CSS version of it?

Comment: The .scss file is already processed and loaded. My problem is that I append an HTML from an external file that is returned from a service call. So the styles loaded were not applied on this appended HTML. So, when I use ViewEncapsulation.None, the styles work, but they override the styles in the external parent component too. So I want a way to reload the styles when the service returns a response and I append the HTML content to my html and reflect only within my component.

Answer (score 0):

> So the styles loaded were not applied on this appended HTML

By default Angular component styles have a scope of a corresponding component. This is done by adding an attribute selector like `[_xyz123]`, where `_xyz123` is an internal random component identifier generated by a compiler. Since you load an HTML from an external source, this HTML doesn't have those attributes or they don't match, so the component's styles are not applied to newly added HTML code.

> So, when I use ViewEncapsulation.None, the styles work, but they override the styles in the external parent component too.

`ViewEncapsulation.None` basically removes the component's scope by eliminating attribute selector and effectively make component's styles global.

> So I want a way to reload the styles when the service returns a response and I append the HTML content to my html and reflect only within my component

What you need is a combination of `ViewEncapsulation.None` with a unique class selector.
A unique class selector will prevent component's styles from leaking outside of your component. `ViewEncapsulation.None` will ensure that component's styles are applied to the appended HTML.